# excel - how to connect a graph max with original (0,0) point

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, drawing

If I have a spreadsheet that has the following data:

```
   A       
0  0  
1  2  
2  4    
3  4    
4  6
```

- 0-4 X Axis
- A is Y Axis

First point is `(0,0)`
Second Point is `(1,2)`
Third point is `(2,4)`
Last Point is `(4,6)`

I select my data and do -> Charts -> Line -> pick line from there, it draws the graph of this one table of values. When I draw a chart based on this I get my line correctly. How do I connect `(0,0)` with `(4,6)` in a straight line in excel? The reason I need it is because I have some other graphs that are going to be either in one or the other side of the connection line. I need to be able to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 3):

Use scatter plot instead of line chart, it's more suitable for your goal.

Enter (0,0) also at the end of your series then insert - charts - scatter - scatter with straight lines (last ones).

This way also you'll be able to manage other charts in a more flexible way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add and format a new series on the chart with the data for the extra line. Depending on your needs (markers etc.), you might need to switch to an XY chart type.

If you do not want the new series to show up in the chart legend, then click on the new series name in the legend and press 'Delete'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not very demanding on accuracy, a linear trendline should do the trick (the 2nd point of the straight line will be at (4,6.1332) instead of (4,6)).

Just right click on your line graph -> Add trendline -> select "linear" radio button and select the "Set Intercept" checkbox and type in "0" at the associated textbox.